# What, if any, are the actual changes suggested by this edit

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits

I recently received [an edit for my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28363556). I looked at the changes, and it looks like the 7 words that the editor suggests replacing are spelled exactly the same as the ones that they would be replacing. So, I'm a little confused. Am I missing something? What, if any, are the actual edits? Should I reject the edits since they don't seem to change anything?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When reviewing an edit, make sure to look at the Markdown view for the post, because only looking at the rendered output can sometimes make it hard to see what's actually happening even with a side-by-side comparison.

In this case, they added backticks to the code terms in your answer, which is an edit that I would approve. The side-by-side comparison also shows "Typically" as changed because they deleted one of the spaces before it. I'm not sure why they did this, considering they didn't change the other instances of double spaces (perhaps they were going to make another change as part of that but decided not to?), but it doesn't actually matter – HTML doesn't render double spaces anyway unless you use invisible characters, `&nbsp;`, or some other workaround – so I wouldn't let that stop me from approving it, or using the "Improve Edit" option if the inconsistency bothers you.